# Find number of sets of x from a range of quantities

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

Looking for an excel formula that would automate the creation of sets, each set to have x number of uniuqe colours, let say 4.

e.g.

first set will be 360 of each green, yellow, blue, pink
second set will be 120 of each green, white, black, brown (as yellow, blue and pink have been all used up)

| Colour | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Green | 800 |
| Yellow | 360 |
| Blue | 360 |
| Pink | 360 |
| White | 240 |
| Black | 240 |
| Brown | 120 |

Tried to use LARGE(A:A,4), but it's not working that well with a larger set of data.

Comment: Probably better to add a "expected results" table as well. Could shed some light on why the 240 was skipped for example.

Comment: @Notus_Panda; How I read this; **Step 1**: Find the highest quantity that has 4+ colors with that exact (or larger) quantity. **Step 2**: Deduct this quantity of only the first 4 color's that matched, their quantity. **Step 3**: Keep iterating untill no more combination's of 4 can be made.

Answer (score 6):

Very lovely query to work on and think about. Here is one option. I took the liberty to display results of each set in a concatenated fashion (you could adapt this if need be), including the similarity in the form of quantity.

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(x,LAMBDA(f,r,c,q,n,LET(y,XLOOKUP(n,MAP(q,LAMBDA(i,SUM(N(q>=i)))),q,0,1),z,TAKE(FILTER(c,q>=y),n),IF(y,f(f,VSTACK(r,HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(", ",,z),y)),c,q-y+y*ISNA(XMATCH(c,z,0)),n),r))),x(x,{"Set","Quantity"},A2:A8,B2:B8,B10))
```

This is a formula that is going to recurse itself as long as there are combinations to be made where `n<=colors`. This; `x(x,{"Set","Quantity"},A2:A8,B2:B8,B10)`, is the important bit where you can invoke the function using the given parameters.

More in-depth; The idea here is that `f(f,r,c,q,n)` is recursive where:

- `f` - Is the function's name;
- `r` - The current array. You'd notice I start of with just headers and `VSTACK()` another line in each iteration;
- `c` - A simple reference to the possible colors;
- `q` - A simple reference to the starting quantities. You'd notice that each iteration the quantities of those colors that are picked for that particular iteration would drop. I suppose this could be a bit tricky to comprehend so I made a little figure to demonstrate this for `n=4`:

[image]

- `n` - A reference to the variable that tells the function how many colors need to be combined in each iteration.

---

Below you'll find what the answer (in my interpretation) would be when `n=2`:

[image]

[image]

---

Below you'll find what the answer (in my interpretation) would be when `n=5`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want, but doesn't seem to be working in Excel 2016?

Comment: When n=2, shouldn't D4 not use 80 remaining green?

Comment: @user23347991 unfortunately this answer is office365 bases using dynamic array functions. And I've edited the anwer to include graps to depict why my answer with `n=2` does not include `80` as it never been the highest possible common value. Anyways, that's how I interpreted your question.

Comment: Quite remarkable of a formula, I felt almost as lost as I get with codegolf answers but I feel with each of these sort of answers from you, I've gained a bit more insight on how to construct these myself, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Notus_Panda. Let me know if you need some help digesting the above.

Comment: I've done it in several waves in the past 2 weeks of looking at it and delving a bit deeper into it so I'm good for now, haha but thanks for the offer.